# How to bypass MDS-CS in BlackBerry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mds-cs

I have sample tcp server running @ localhost:5050. Connecting to it from BlackBerry is via MDS-CS simulator,and it caches the data with max of 8192. From the Blackberry forums, i understood that, there is a way to bypass it directly to the server.

My Configuration is as follows,

```
IDE : BlackBerry JDE 4.7.0 
Platform : Vista 
Server : TCP Server running localhost:5050
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use direct TCP.  When running in the simulator you can just add ";deviceside=true" to the end of your URL.  Out on a real phone I don't think it is so easy - I'm also looking for a solution.

Comment: thanks :), i have been dwelling in BBforums for the last 2 days , .. lol .. knew it had a simple solution , YIPPEE

Comment: It works on a real phone too, but on a real phone you may also have to configure your TCP APN - partly depending on your device & carrier.  BlackBerryFaq has a decent list: http://www.blackberryfaq.com/index.php/Carrier_specific_APN/TCP_settings

Comment: Also note that you only need to set up an APN on GSM carriers, and even then some of the newer devices already have an APN built in to the device (so you don't have to specify it on the URL).  CDMA devices work without an APN.

Comment: So we dont need mds simulator to be started when we are adding deviceside=true to the url???